# How do I change my directory color?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, command

Using linux, I changed my client's home directory.

After then, when client enter 'ls'(file list command) into consol, I found that all of directory, files, etc color are white.

I tried to change '/etc/DIR_COLORS' file, and copied that into client's home directory but that never work. Even if I tried to input 'export LS_COLORS="di=0;36' command manually, without that client's, every members' work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore your client's `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, and/or `.cshrc`. They contain many settings, including the alias required to enabled colored `ls` output.

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

After restoring the startup files, log out and log in again to test that they work.

Comment: I also copied .bashrc, I'll try .profile or .cshrc

Comment: The alias may have been in a separate file. I keep mine in .bash_aliases

Comment: COOL! it works.Thanks Rob. I moved .profile file into default client's folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the user's .bashrc

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```